# b.setDisabled is not a function

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make the bot disable the button after it's used, but it isn't working, because it is saying that `b.setDisabled` is not a function. How can I solve this?

```
const {
    SlashCommandBuilder,
    EmbedBuilder,
    ButtonStyle,
    ButtonBuilder,
    ActionRowBuilder,
    ActionRow,
} = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName("highlow")
        .setDescription(" | Starts a new high or low game!"),
    async execute(interaction) {
        const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
        const hintNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
        const row = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(
            new ButtonBuilder()
                .setLabel("High")
                .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Secondary)
                .setCustomId("high"),
            new ButtonBuilder()
                .setCustomId("low")
                .setLabel("Low")
                .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Secondary),
            new ButtonBuilder()
                .setCustomId("correct")
                .setLabel("Same")
                .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Secondary)
        );
        const sent = await interaction.reply({
            content: `Is my number higher or lower than ${hintNumber}?`,
            components: [row],
        });
        const collector = sent.createMessageComponentCollector({
            filter: (i) =>
                i.user.id === interaction.user.id && i.message.id === sent.id,
            time: 30000,
            max: 1,
        });
        let won = false;
        collector.on("collect", async (i) => {
            await i.deferUpdate({ fetchReply: true });
            row.forEach((b) => b.setDisabled(true));
            if (i.customId === "high") {
                if (hintNumber > randomNumber) {
                    row.forEach((b) => {
                        if (b.customId === "high") b.setStyle(ButtonStyle.Danger);
                    });
                    await interaction.editReply({
                        content: `Sadge, you got it wrong! It was ${randomNumber}`,
                        components: [row],
                    });
                    won = false;
                } else {
                    row.forEach((b) => {
                        if (b.customId === "high") b.setStyle(ButtonStyle.Success);
                    });
                    await interaction.editReply({
                        content: `You guessed the number! It was ${randomNumber}`,
                        components: [row],
                    });
                    won = true;
                }
            } else if (i.customId === "low") {
                if (hintNumber < randomNumber) {
                    row.forEach((b) => {
                        if (b.customId === "low") b.setStyle(ButtonStyle.Danger);
                    });
                    await interaction.editReply({
                        content: `Sadge, you got it wrong! It was ${randomNumber}`,
                        components: [row],
                    });
                    won = false;
                } else {
                    row.forEach((b) => {
                        if (b.customId === "low") b.setStyle(ButtonStyle.Success);
                    });
                    await interaction.editReply({
                        content: `You are right! It was ${randomNumber}`,
                        components: [row],
                    });
                    won = true;
                }
            } else if (i.customId === "correct" && hintNumber === randomNumber) {
                row.forEach((b) => {
                    if (b.customId === "correct") b.setStyle(ButtonStyle.Success);
                });
                await interaction.editReply({
                    content: `You guessed the number! It was ${randomNumber}`,
                    components: [row],
                });
                won = true;
            } else {
                await interaction.editReply({
                    content: `Sadge, you got it wrong! It was ${randomNumber}`,
                    components: [row],
                });
                won = false;
            }
        });
        collector.on("end", async (collected) => {
            if (!won && collected.size === 0) {
                [row].forEach((b) => b.setDisabled(true));
                await interaction.editReply({
                    content: `You didn't guess the number! It was ${randomNumber}`,
                    components: [row],
                });
            }
        });
    },
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe use `row.components.forEach(b => b.setDisabled(true))`